# Should I create a .factory in order to share a variable's value to two ajax requests?

Tags: ajax, angularjs, service, jsonp

Using angularjs I have made two ajax json requests, the first request is retrieving channel's online / offline status and the second ajax json request is for the channel's info (logo, name, status etc).

I assigned the variable signal to 'data.stream' which is the online / offline status for channels to share signal between json requests. In Google Developer console I am receiving a value of null. I did some research here http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/beginner2expert-services.html and found that using a service might be a solution. I followed the directions but I'm still unable to get the scope between json request to recognize signal.

I read that rootscope could be used but it's not recommend, not sure how true that is because a novice using angular but I want start my angular journey by applying best practices.

Recap: Using Angular Ajax to make a jsonp request to twitch api, I am make two requests one to retrieve the online / offline status of channels in my streamers array, and the other ajax json request is to retrieve the channel's info, and I need the scope of the variable signal which has been assigned the value data.stream to be seen between ajax jsonp requests. Please let me know if this is a logical approach or if I'm "going around the world again".

Here is a plunker: plnkr.co/edit/6sb39NktX7CwfnQFxNNX

```
// creating a service for signal ?    
app.factory('signal', function() {
                var signal = {};

                return signal;
            })

            // declaring my TwitchController and dependencies 
            app.controller('TwitchController', ['$scope', '$http', 'signal', function($scope, $http, signal) {
                // streamers array with array of channels
                var streamers = ["freecodecamp", "storbeck", "terakilobyte", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "thomasballinger", "noobs2ninjas", "beohoff", "medrybw"];

                $scope.imgs;
                $scope.signal = signal;

                var self = this;

                //empty array
                self.info = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < streamers.length; i++) {
                    var url = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/";
                    var streamUrl = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/";
                    var callback = "/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
                    //json ajax request for channels online and offline status
                    $http.jsonp(streamUrl + streamers[i] + callback).success(function(data) {

                        //provides status of shows online and offline
                        signal = data.stream;
                        console.log(signal)

                    });
                    // json ajax request for channels and channel's info
                    $http.jsonp(url + streamers[i] + callback).success(function(data) {
                        // if channel does not have a logo image, this jpg will be the placeholder 
                // if statement test channel status (online or offline)
                        if (!signal) {
                            signal = "offline";
                        } else if (signal) {
                            signal = 'online';
                        }

                        // pushing retreive data from twitch.tv into array self.info 
                        self.info.push(data);

                    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue here is async call to $http. You need to use $http.then and chain the promises. You do not need a factory for this instance but it is best practice to have one that just returns your info object. I didn't know exactly the format you wanted so I created one. Here is the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ecwk0vGMJCvkqCbZa7Cw?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('Twitch', []);

// declaring my TwitchController and dependencies 
   app.controller('TwitchController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    // streamers array with array of channels
    var streamers = ['freecodecamp', 'storbeck','terakilobyte', 'habathcx', 'RobotCaleb', 'thomasballinger', 'noobs2ninjas', 'beohoff', 'medrybw' ];

    //empty array
    $scope.info = [];

    var url = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/';
    var streamUrl = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/';
    var callback = '/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK';

    angular.forEach(streamers, function(stream) {
      //json ajax request for channels online and offline status
      $http.jsonp(streamUrl + stream + callback).then(function (data) {
        //provides status of shows online and offline

        // json ajax request for channels and channel's info
        $http.jsonp(url + stream + callback).then(function (channelData) {
          // pushing retrieve data from twitch.tv into array self.info
           $scope.info.push(
            {
              url: url + stream,
              stream: stream,
              status: !data.stream ? 'offline' : 'online', // ternary statement test channel status (online or offline)
              logo: channelData.data.logo ?  channelData.data.logo : 'placeholderlogo.jpg' // if channel does not have a logo image, this jpg will be the placeholder
            }
          );
        });
      });
    });
  }]);
```

Comment: medrybw broadcasts 24/7 so the status should be online. In chrome the placeholderlogo.jpg representing logo for all channels when it shouldn't be, and more importantly the channel's info are no longer populating my expressions. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should post your code in plunkr so you can track down your issues. It is not clear what object you want to build. You can change the $scope.info.push()  to include as much data from the channelData object as needed.  Not sure about the online status. I just know it was returning a null status from data.stream and that it was what you were using to determine if it was offline / online. The code works you just have not explained what you REALLY want for the resulting object.

Comment: Hi @enkode here is the URL to my Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/6sb39NktX7CwfnQFxNNX

Comment: I updated the plunker to fix your issues you were injecting signal but there was not signal service...  It now works and you will just have to track down your online offline logic as you said that is incorrect. Also you will have to set a proper missing image as that was not supplied. This is now working so please mark the answer as correct.

Comment: I think I figured out that you want the data.status to determine if they are online / offline. I updated the plunkr for this scenario. Now you should just change the default image to a live hosted image.